# Inner join with where clause

Tags: mysql, inner-join, where-clause

This is my query

```
 $searched =  'SELECT first_name, surname, team, id, time FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE "'.$firstname.'%" AND surname LIKE "'.$surname.'%"'
```

I need to do an inner join on a table of teams.

Structure is as follows.

```
id
teamname
slug
```

I need to get the teamname the join is in the teams.id and users.id.

I just can't seem to get the syntax right.

Comment: inner join  teams on teams.id=users.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `INNER JOIN`. Also `time` is a [keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) for MySQL and it's better to escape it. Fields `id` should be used with table name because they are ambiguous. Finally you are under SQL Injection threat.

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.surname, users.team, users.id AS users_id, `time`
FROM users 
INNER JOIN teams
ON teams.id = users.id
WHERE users.first_name LIKE "'.$firstname.'%" AND users.surname LIKE "'.$surname.'%"
```

Also, is there any particular reason that the JOIN should be on `teams.id` and `users.id`. They are supposed to be different things.

Comment: time is NOT a reserved word

Comment: @Strawberry, Is this not a keyword?

Comment: It is a keyword, but not a reserved word.

Comment: Yes. It's a keyword (whatever that means). It's not reserved.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I was lost in translation. I fixed that to be proper.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not have either `team.id = users.teamid` or `team.userid = users.id`  in the where condition? Also in the select you have used "team". I guess it should be "teamname".

The SQL should probably be

```
SELECT 
    first_name, 
    surname, 
    teamname, 
    id, 
    time 
FROM 
    users,
    teams
WHERE 
        first_name LIKE "'.$firstname.'%" 
    AND surname LIKE "'.$surname.'%"'
    AND users.teamid = teams.id
```